# IIS 7.5 and ARR - Server.MapPath showing path on ARR Server not Content Server

Tags: iis, arr, web-farm

I am currently building a Web Farm using ARR and the Web Farm Framework.

We have two ARR servers that are part of their own NLB cluster with the Web Farm containing two identical content servers.

I've deployed an application to the farm to do some testing and come across a problem. When trying to upload a file through said web application (or any other for that matter) that resides on the content servers I receive the following error:

> Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\content\attachments\8' is denied.

After a little detective work, I discovered that this path is one that resides on the ARR server and not the content server where the application is and I would expect the file to be uploaded.

The application establishes where it needs to upload to by using `HttpContext.Server.MapPath(@"\content\attachments\" + id);`

The path I would expect to see would be `D:\Web Data\Application\Content\Attachments\8` which is a local path that exists in the same place across all content servers in the web farm.

I know there are ways to do it by changing the applications themselves, but if we can help it, the Developers shouldn't need to do so.

Is there something in ARR/IIS that needs configuring/can be configured so that applications are able to see the file system on the machine they actually reside on within the web farm?

Comment: when you are using the webserver directly - it works?

Comment: Yes. All seems to run fine as intended when accessing the application directly on either of the content servers.

Comment: Try to send the error message by email, as I suspect that ARR rewrite the headers and content fields.